# Register level access in linux device driver

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, gpio, angstrom-linux

I have only 2 weeks experience in linux driver development, but have good experience on embedded c programming.  I have only tried character device driver in linux.  Now i wish to try a device driver for a set of LED's connected to GPIO.  I am using BeagleBone Black.  I wish to access it from the register level and not by just calling any driver. (I am doing this to learn the basics)

I wish my driver GPIO access code to be somewhat like below

```
void SetLED(unsigned char LED,unsigned char Status){
    //Read the port register
    //BitWise Operation according to function parameters
    //Write back to the register
}
```

But i need some help on how to access the registers directly in linux.  I have got the actual address of the port OUT register from the datasheet as 0x4804C13C

Pardon me if i am breaking any basics in my question.  I am really new to linux.

Comment: A nit, but many modern peripherals have optimized their register interface so that the read-modify-write sequence is rarely needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your driver has to call

```
struct resource *request_mem_region(unsigned long start, unsigned long len, char *name);
```

to register exclusive access to that region of memory.

Then it must use `ioread8()`,`ioread16()`, etc. and `iowrite8()`,`iowrite16()`, etc.

Comment: *"So your driver only has to call...request_mem_region()"* -- Your answer is incomplete, and therefore incorrect.  The registers are not likely to mapped into virtual address space, which is what **ioremap()** is for.

Comment: Don’t confuse people, please. On x86 one can find MMIO as well as IO. Moreover, *ioreadN()* and *iowriteN()* is overkill if you know that registers are available through MMIO.